# How to catch the response value in Angular?

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-web-api

i have an object in api  that returns in the response it cointains the data and messeage.

```
public class ServiceResponse<T>
{
    public T? Data { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

when there an error for example i return it like that in the repo:

```
return new ServiceResponse<GetBookModel> { Success = false, Message = "This Book have open Borrowings, close them to delete." };
```

and the controller sends it like that to the client:

```
 [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ServiceResponse<GetBookModel>>> DeleteBook([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        var response = await UnitOfWork.BookRepository.DeleteBookAsync(id);
        
        if (response.Success== false)
        {
            return NotFound(response);
        }
       
        await UnitOfWork.Save();
        
        return Ok(response);
    }
```

now my problem occours in the client side when i try to get the response message.
its works when there isnt an error but if there is an error i get it as undefined.

this is my code:

```
removeBook(id: any) {
alertify.confirm("Remove Book", "do you want to remove this book?", () => {
  this._bookService.deleteBook(id).subscribe(r => {
    this.mssg = r;
    this.getAll();
    alertify.success(this.mssg.message);
  }, error => {
    console.log(this.mssg);
    if (this.mssg === undefined) {
      alertify.error("Book wasn't deleted.")
    }
    else {
      alertify.error(this.mssg.message);
    }
  });
}, function () {

})
```

the mssg gets the response value and i can get the message.
but in error the consloe.log returns undefined.
thx in advance!!

Comment: What about on network tab ? If response is undefined means its coming from backend like that.

Comment: i found a solution apperently to use the message i should append to the response as error.error.message.